# Javascript - copy field values without knowing all the fields

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, input

I have input fields that are associated together, and need to copy value from "parent" field to "child" field when something is entered into "parent" field. In short, it should work like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p80rnwjb/).

```
<form id="form1" method="..." action="...">
    <p><label>Enter something: <input name="parent1"></label><br>
    <label>and see what happens: <input name="child1"></label></p>
</form>
<script>
var form = document.getElementById('form1');
form.elements.parent1.onblur = function () {
    var form = this.form;
    form.elements.child1.value = form.elements.parent1.value;
};
</script>
```

Simple. Now here's the problem: I don't know how many fields the form will have (these are created dynamically). All I know is there will always be the same number of parent/child fields and their names will be the same. So form may look like:

```
<input name="parent[59]"> <input name="child[59]">
<input name="parent[87]"> <input name="child[87]">
```

...and so on. Yes, the field names are the same, except the number (because these need to be submitted as arrays) will be different.

How do I rewrite JS code, so when user enters something into `parent[59]`, its value gets copied to `child[59]`, when user enters something into `parent[87]`, its value gets copied to `child[87]`, etc?

I couldn't even get it working with single field when names of input fields contain square brackets [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q64v0k8y/1/)

(yes, I tried escaping brackets with `\` but no luck)

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. This is **why** SO wouldn't let you post that jsFiddle link as an actual link. Next time, please don't ignore the message. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Very surprising to see this in a 4-year-plus member with 55 previous questions and 15 answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution is to use [an Event Delegate](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to listen to all *input* events on the DOM, then if the target (i.e. [*event.target*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)) element has a *name* attribute which contains the string literal "*parent*" (check using [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)), replace that with "*child*" (using [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)) and update the element with that name attribute.

```js
document.addEventListener('input', function(inputEvent) {
  if (inputEvent.target.name.indexOf('parent') > -1) {
    var childName = inputEvent.target.name.replace('parent', 'child');
    document.forms[0].elements[childName].value = inputEvent.target.value;
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <input name="parent[59]"> <input name="child[59]">
  <br /><br />
  <input name="parent[87]"> <input name="child[87]">
  <br /><br />
  <input name="parent[187]"> <input name="child[187]">
  <br /><br />
  <input name="parent[3]"> <input name="child[3]">
</form>
```

Compare that with the non-delegate approach (Adding an event listener to all parent inputs, which requires iterating over DOM elements with class name containing *parent*) in [this jsperf testcase](https://jsperf.com/parent-child-value-synchronization). When I ran it, the non-delegate case was 33% slower.

Comparing the two approaches through the lens of [algorithmic complexity](http://discrete.gr/complexity/), the delegate approach is a *constant time algorithm*, so it is Θ( 1 )<sup>[1](http://discrete.gr/complexity/)</sup>, whereas the non-delegate approach is *linear*, or  Θ( n )<sup>[1](http://discrete.gr/complexity/)</sup>. In other words, the worst-case for the event delegate approach is that it runs once per page load, whereas the other approach will have the lambda function run as many times as there are elements with the string literal "parent" in the name attribute.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://discrete.gr/complexity/</sub>

Comment: Thanks, the solution seems to be really elegant.

Answer (score 3):

You can target all elements based on the attribute, and then fetch the number from the name

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[name^=parent]').forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var n = this.name.split('[').pop();
    document.querySelector('[name="child[' + n + '"]').value = this.value;
  });
});
```

```html
<input name="parent[59]"> <input name="child[59]">
<br /><br />
<input name="parent[87]"> <input name="child[87]">
<br /><br />
<input name="parent[187]"> <input name="child[187]">
<br /><br />
<input name="parent[3]"> <input name="child[3]">
```

Comment: Jesus Christ, that's one of the fastest solutions I received here (especially because it's a solution with multiple lines of code). Thank you so much.